# Python inexplicably increases list size in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pycharm

I'm trying to learn Python, and am doing a project that involves me comparing the average birth number on Friday 13 compared with average births for every other day. I got pretty far but ran into an issue. For some reason unknown to me, when the list I pass in suddenly increases in size from 3653 to 4018. When I try and run the function, I get the error

```
in average_per_date
    other += each[4]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'
```

I know there are workarounds, but I'm confused why the code I wrote doesn't work. Thanks!

```
def average_per_date(data):
    num_of_fri13 = 0
    num_of_other = 0
    fri13 = 0
    other = 0
    for each in data:
        print(num_of_fri13 + num_of_other)
        if (each[2] == 13) & (each[3] == 5):
            num_of_fri13 += 1
            fri13 += each[4]
        else:    
            num_of_other += 1
            other += each[4]

    return [(fri13 / num_of_fri13), (other / num_of_other)]
```

I would show an image of debugging but I need reputation to, but when I do debug, it shows the size of the list to be 3653 at the beginning of the function, and then 4018 when I try to iterate over it.

Comment: The logical operator in Python is `and`, not `&`. Also, please include a sample of `data`.

Comment: How does your `data` look? More specifically, in the iteration where you get the error, what is in `each`? (The easiest way to do that is to do `print(each)` just above your `if`, and see what the last `each` printed before the error looks like)